# Printf, post or Cout for printing my results on Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, vector, printf, cout

I am new to Xcode (using Xcode 7.0) and I am currently working on a project so as to exercise. 
I have a `vector` that I want to print, but I don't really know how is the syntax of `printf` for a `vector`. 
I was also told to use `post();` to print my results but it doesn't work.
Could I maybe use `cout`? And if yes, how is the syntax for printing a `vector`?

I am using C.                                                              I have these:

```
    void addGestureTemplate(ofxGVFGesture & gestureTemplate);                         ofxGVFGesture & getGestureTemplate(int index); 
vector<ofxGVFGesture> & getAllGestureTemplates();
int getNumberOfGestureTemplates();
vector<float>& getGestureTemplateSample(int gestureIndex, float cursor);
```

And I want to print the x,y,z elements of the gesture, when it is added in the system.

Comment: What language? How do you define the vector? I don't think this is connected with Xcode (wrong tags) but with a given language.

Comment: Delete this comment and paste this code within your question. Format it as it's hardly readable atm. This "comment" is a part of your question and should stay there.